# Azure appservice, randomly swaps the running exe

Tags: azure, sockets, tcp, azure-web-app-service

[image: Exe swaps]

We are experiencing some issues with random high latency in our azure appservice. We think it might be cause of this random swap of running .exe's.

You can clearly see the Blue and Green line cross. Does anyone have more insight in where to look. I can't find any information on this.

Comment: @Joey- Have your run the [App service Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics) using Diagnostics and solve problems in Azure portal

Comment: It finds nothing except that there is no code to warmup the instance @VenkateshDodda-MSFT